# I want to stretch the text a little bit more, but, "text-align: justify" isn't doing what I want

Tags: html, css

I wanna make it so it looks like this:

[image]

How do I make it looks like the image provided?(Only with CSS and HTML).

```
<head>

    <title>Webpage With Style</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        #main{

        }

        #title{
            text-align: center;
            position:relative;
            top: 125px;
            font-size: 33px;
        }

        #img-div{

        }

        #image {
            position:relative;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            top: 147;
        }

        #img-caption{

            margin: 160px 80px;
            text-align: justify;
            font-size: 16px;


        }

        /*   position:relative;
            align-self: right;
            top: 180px;  */

        body{
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        #billion{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            top: -510;
            font-size: 16px;

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <main id="main">


        <h1 id="title">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1> 

        <div id="billion">The man who saved a billion lives</div>

        <div id="img-div">

            <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg"id="image">

            <div id="img-caption">Dr. Norman Borlaug, second from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</div>


        </div>

    </main>

</body>
```

see at:

```
    #img-caption{

        margin: 160px 80px;
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 16px;
```

If I remove the "justify" function it won't make a difference, so, it isn't working. I want to stretch the text a little bit more just like the image provided, and, make it looks just alike it.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is overflowing its container and the relatively positioned image caption is being contained.
You can contain your image by giving it a width of <=100%. This will give it and the caption the same amount of horizontal space.

```css
#main {}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 33px;
}

#img-div {}

#image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#img-caption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#billion {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <main id="main">


        <h1 id="title">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1> 

        <div id="billion">The man who saved a billion lives</div>

        <div id="img-div">

            <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg"id="image">

            <div id="img-caption">Dr. Norman Borlaug, second from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</div>


        </div>

    </main>

</body>
```

If you want the image and the caption to overflow the container (although I don't know why you would), you can give the caption absolute positioning, set its whitespace to nowrap, and adjust the width and margins to suit like so:

```css
       #main{
       }

        #title{
            text-align: center;
            position:relative;
            top: 125px;
            font-size: 33px;
        }

        #img-div{
          width: 100%;
          border: 1px solid red;
          overflow: visible;
        }

        #image {
            position:relative;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            top: 147;
        }

        #img-caption{
            position: absolute;
            width: 70%;
            margin: 1% 15%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            white-space: nowrap;

        }

        /*   position:relative;
            align-self: right;
            top: 180px;  */

        body{
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        #billion{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            top: -510;
            font-size: 16px;

        }
```

```html
<body>

    <main id="main">


        <h1 id="title">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1> 

        <div id="billion">The man who saved a billion lives</div>

        <div id="img-div">

            <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg"id="image">

            <div id="img-caption">Dr. Norman Borlaug, second from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</div>


        </div>

    </main>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change/increase the `letter-spacing`

> The letter-spacing CSS property sets the spacing behavior between text characters.
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing)

```css
#main {}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 33px;
}

#img-div {}

#image {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#img-caption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .5px
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#billion {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">

  <h1 id="title">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1>

  <div id="billion">The man who saved a billion lives</div>

  <div id="img-div">

    <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg" id="image">

    <div id="img-caption">Dr. Norman Borlaug, second from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</div>

  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove the "justify" function it won't make a difference, so, it isn't working.

No, of course it isn’t, because `text-align: justify` *by definition* justifies the text in all lines *except the last* - but you only *have* one line of text here to begin with, so that *is* the “last” line as well.

This is to avoid situations where you have text flowing in a way that, say, only two (or three) words make up the last line, and you then get one word on the very left(, one in the middle), and one on the very right, which would look rather awful.

You can use [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) to explicitly specify justified alignment for the last line of text though.

Comment: Your answer would greatly benefit from a code example. Right now it's mostly a link-only answer.

Comment: @MrLister I explained what the problem is, and what alternative can be used - so I don’t think this can be considered a “link-only” answer. (I am fully aware why those are bad, but I don’t think this actually is one.)

Comment: Well, the least you can do is add the disclaimers from the linked page to your answer (some browsers needed the vendor prefix until fairly recently; other browsers require both `text-align-last` and `text-align` to be present, etc.)